# Javascript block element not work

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I'm trying create a simple automatic slideshow with javacript.

```js
var Index = 0;
automatic();

function automatic() {
    var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    for (var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
        slide[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    if (Index > slide.length) {
        Index = 1;
    }
    Index++;
    slide[Index - 1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(automatic, 2000);
}
```

I think the problem stay is `slide[Index - 1].style.display = "block";` because i put an **Alert** before this and when I test the webpage the **Alert** works, and when i put after the **Alert**, he not work.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you calling the function before the page has had time to read it? Shouldn't you be calling the function after you have declared the function?

Comment: Add the html also so we can see where the script is loaded.

Comment: Here is a [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kpm3L3uw/) I have changed the reset for `Index` to `0` and removed the `-1` when targeting the image you want to change the style/display. I have also moved the `Index++;` to the bottom so this will run after changing the image. I couldn't see much point of setting `Index` to `1` when the default is `0`, this also removed the need to use `[Index-1]` in the selector. **Edit:** Changes to the `if` condition `Index == slide.length`

Answer (score 0):

**First**: set the initial value of Index to 1 to avoid working with element -1

**Second**: Change the order of these two lines:

`Index++;`

`if (Index > slide.length+1) { Index = 1; }`

**Third**: the condition should be up to slide.length+1 as I corrected above.

Comment: I have updated the answer from one to three recommendations. Please check again

Comment: Hi again, i tryed with VS Code and this is the error message:

Exception has occurred: TypeError
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at automatic

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```js
var Index = 0;
automatic();

function automatic() {
    var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    for (var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
        slide[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    if (Index >= slide.length) {
        Index = 0;
    }
    Index++;
    slide[Index - 1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(automatic, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, i tryed all indications but don't worked.
I have a code for the buttons and manually works